# Calculating the probability of error while probing

Tags: hashtable

[image]

I was working on this exam question and I am unsure as to whether my interpretation of the question is correct

- **Question 1:** To my understanding, the average number of probes for the first case would be O(1/1-r) and O(1/r ln(1/1-r)) for the second case where r = n/m.
- **Question 2:** This is because another word in the dictionary could hash to the same slot and an incorrectly spelled word might be indicated as corrected because of this
- **Question 3** I'm unsure about this question. Wouldn't m here be 400,031 just like Case 1? Also, I'm not sure as to how to go about computing the probability for this question.

Any help with regard to Question 3 would be appreciated!

Comment: (a)/Q1 can only be answered by making some further assumptions: with open addressing, the number of probes depends on how you select alternative buckets to probe after finding colliding elements: the question doesn't specify any probing behaviour, but you could list averages for say linear and quadratic probing, and rehashing with alternative hash functions.  You can find formulas for this easily online, e.g. [here](http://cs360.cs.ua.edu/notes/hashing_formulas.pdf).

Comment: You're right about (b)/Q2.  For your Q3, you're forgetting the hash table needed space for 20 characters, while the "signature file" operates in bits - you get 160 of those for every hash bucket.